# Latex centering figures and tables when alone on a page

Tags: tables, floats, vertical-alignment

I have 4 tables that need to follow each other (they are in the appendix). Two fit on a single page together but there is plenty of space left (thought not enough for another table). I would like to vertically center these two tables so that they don't look weird. How can I do that?

Here is my code (I want the tables to vertically centered):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{float} % For H

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    8  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  8  &  8  \\ \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Order = 1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    8  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  8  &  8  \\ \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Order = 2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    8  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  8  &  8  \\ \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Order = 3}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    8  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  8  &  8  \\ \hline
    8  &  4  \\ \hline  4  &  8  \\ \hline
    4  &  8  \\ \hline  8  &  4  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Order = 4}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done.

Comment: Drop the `[H]` location specifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best *not* to use the `[H]` float placement here. Rather use a `[p]`age of floats setting. Additionally, if need be, you could use the [`afterpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) to flush any pending floats:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-50]% A lot of text.

\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Some figure.}

  \vspace{4\baselineskip}

  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Some other figure.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Some figure.}

  \vspace{4\baselineskip}

  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Some other figure.}
\end{figure}
\afterpage{\clearpage}% Flush any pending floats after _this_ page.

\lipsum[1-50]% A lot of text.
\end{document}
```

While it may not be apparent in the image above, the floats were placed somewhere mid-page on the page preceding the placement. Also not that, for the sake of "keeping things together", the two figures were placed in a single float. That's fine, since the `\caption` for each separates them visually from the output, as well as the space between (which you can adjust).

The above approach also works with `table`s.

For a general discussion on float placement, see the FAQ [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764).